# Unable to post telemetry data using HTTP from command line

Tags: thingsboard

Unable to post telemetry data using HTTP from command line, I can not get any message in my thingsboard Platform

[image: example]

```
 C:\Users\Administrator>curl -v -X POST -d "{\"temperature\": 25}" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mdULJGYox2jQmDmFbZID/telemetry --header "Content-Type:application/json"
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
    *   Trying ::1...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
    > POST /api/v1/mdULJGYox2jQmDmFbZID/telemetry HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost:8080
    > User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
    > Accept: */*
    > Content-Type:application/json
    > Content-Length: 19
    >
    * upload completely sent off: 19 out of 19 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 200
    < Vary: Origin
    < Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
    < Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
    < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    < Pragma: no-cache
    < Expires: 0
    < Content-Length: 0
    < Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2020 07:36:48 GMT
    <
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Are there active rule chain(s) to save the telemetry data? The default rule-chain should do this, when you never touched them

Comment: I'm on https://demo.thingsboard.io/signup, and the device can easily get the data, but the one deployed locally can't get the data anyway

Answer (score 0):

i'm new to thingsboard. I also encountered the same issue right now. But it works when i use postman to send the same http request to a locally installed se. So maybe it gets stuck in the curl command.

Comment: seems better as a comment

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the answer party, but I've found out this syntax works:

```
curl -v -X POST https://iot.server.com/api/v1/deviceToken/telemetry -d "{"Hello":"World"}" --header "Content-Type:text/plain"
```

To me the trick was in adding the --header part
Hopefully it will help anyone who is still having this problem.